# Annoying 5px whitespace between Avada wordpress theme divs; margin-top: -5px works but padding-top: -5px doesnt work

Tags: html, css, layout, wordpress

I am having a very difficult time getting rid of this persistent 5px whitespace on my website [eternalminerals.com](http://eternalminerals.com)

I highlighted it in this screenshot: http://s15.postimg.org/de4sjvqob/5pxwhitespace.png

In google chrome, if I edit the element to have a margin-top: -5px, it gets rid of the whitespace, but since I am using Avada shortcodes, I cannot attach this style to it since it is a shortcode:

```
<p style="text-align: center; margin-top: -10px; font-size: 19px !important; line-height: 42px !important; color: #FFE396!important; font-family: 'MuseoSlab500Regular', Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;"><strong>That's my opinion. I am Dr George Lundberg, at large at The Eternal Minerals of Life.</strong></p>
</div>
[/raw]
[fullwidth backgroundcolor="#140100" backgroundimage="" backgroundrepeat="no-repeat" backgroundposition="top left" backgroundattachment="fixed" bordersize="0px" bordercolor="#e5e4e4" paddingTop="-5px" paddingBottom="0px"]
<br>
[ajax_load_more post_type="testimonials-widget" posts_per_page="5" pause="true" transition="fade" button_label="Click to show testimonials from real physicians"]
[/fullwidth]
```

As you can see, paddingTop="-5px" doesn't cut it. Does anyone have a better idea on how to get rid of this whitespace? I will keep trying and keep you posted on my findings. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I see a flash object popping out in this place.

Comment: Can't you add `margin-top-5px` to  `class="fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box"` ?

Comment: Xufox, I don't use any flash except maybe it is from the youtube embed? vivekkupadhyay, wouldn't that affect all of the fusion-fullwidth fullwidth-box? It only seems to happen in this one place and I dont want to add a margin-top: -5px to all of them

Comment: Might I suggest increasing the height of the background image by 5 pixels. Also, there are more things wrong with the site: on my screen, the text doesn't end there where the 5px gap is; see [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/cXGpK.jpg). Only when I zoom out does the text fit in the top area.

Comment: Also, `padding-top:-5px` doesn't do anything. See [definition](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/box.html#value-def-padding-width): "Unlike margin properties, values for padding values cannot be negative"

Comment: Mr Lister, thank you so much for the screenshot. I am curious why that is showing like that on your end. If I increase the height of the background image, it makes my screen look elongated with empty space... Hmmmm I wonder why the height is different for you. It looks flush on my end. Could your browser zoom size be more than 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So although the originally accepted answer of using the line-height worked, it messed up all of the line-heights on the page, and after a little bit more tinkering, all that was needed was to add the `margin-bottom: -5px;` to the canvas element.

This solution is less invasive and achieves the same visual effect, so I will be accepting my own answer as the solution instead. Sorry Masoom!

This is the code now:

```
<canvas id="matrix" style="margin-left:-20px;margin-bottom:-5px;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hmm, although it looks fine in my browser, I am still seeing the whitespace on other people's browsers. Maybe I need to make it more than -5px? (like -10px)?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the `line-height` taking for all the individual elements. After changing the `line-height` of the body tag that space will disappear. Below is the code.

```
body {
    line-height: 0.7;
}
```

As all the elements are having individual `line-height` you can give even lesser value (<0.7) for `line-height` of the body tag.

Comment: Curious how you were able to figure this out? How did you know it was the line-height/what clues gave it away?

Comment: I had a similar issue before and its because of `margin` given for the inner elements. So at first I thought this is also same type, but it is not. Then I have seen huge `line-height`s given for all the elements and I changed it. This did that trick. Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Masoom!